# Writing a chunk of MPI distributed data via hdf5 in fortran

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, mpi, hdf5

I have a 3d array distributed into different MPI processes:

```
real :: DATA(i1:i2, j1:j2, k1:k2)
```

where `i1, i2, ...` are different for each MPI process, but the MPI grid is cartesian.

For simplicity let's assume I have a `120 x 120 x 120` array, and 27 MPI processes distributed as `3 x 3 x 3` (so that each processor has an array of size `40 x 40 x 40`).

Using `hdf5` library I need to write only a slice of that data, say, a slice that goes through the middle perpendicular to the second axis. The resulting (global) array would be of size `120 x 1 x 120`.

I'm a bit confused on how to properly use the `hdf5` here, and how to generalize full `DATA` writing (which I can do). The problem is, not each MPI thread is going to be writing. For instance, in the case above, only 9 processes will have to write something, others (which are on the +/-x and +/-z edges of the cube) will not have to, since they don't contain any chunk of the slab I need.

I tried the `chunking` technique [described here](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Chunking+in+HDF5), but it looks like that's just for a single thread.

Would be very grateful if the hdf5 community can help me in this :)

Comment: As SOG writes, you need to select the hyperslab on each process. Some can have size zero but *must* do the collective call anyway. Alternative: write from a single process. The dataset creation, etc, must still be done collectively. This can all be done with the standard HDF5 library.

Answer (score 1):

When writing an HDF5 dataset in parallel, all MPI processes must participate in the operation (even if a certain MPI process does not have values to write).

If you are not bound to a specific library, take a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com). Based on what I could understand from the use-case you have posted, here goes an example on how to write data in parallel in Fortran using HDFql.

```fortran
PROGRAM Example

    ! use HDFql module (make sure it can be found by the Fortran compiler)
    USE HDFql

    ! declare variables
    REAL(KIND=8), DIMENSION(40, 40, 40) :: values
    CHARACTER(2) :: start
    INTEGER :: state
    INTEGER :: x
    INTEGER :: y
    INTEGER :: z

    ! create an HDF5 file named "example.h5" and use (i.e. open) it in parallel
    state = hdfql_execute("CREATE AND USE FILE example.h5 IN PARALLEL")

    ! create a dataset named "dset" of data type double of three dimensions (size 120x120x120)
    state = hdfql_execute("CREATE DATASET dset AS DOUBLE(120, 120, 120)");

    ! populate variable "values" with certain values
    DO x = 1, 40
        DO y = 1, 40
            DO z = 1, 40
                values(z, y, x) = hdfql_mpi_get_rank() * 100000 + (x * 1600 + y * 40 + z)
            END DO
        END DO
    END DO

    ! register variable "values" for subsequent use (by HDFql)
    state = hdfql_variable_register(values)

    IF (hdfql_mpi_get_rank() < 3) THEN
        ! insert (i.e. write) values from variable "values" into dataset "dset" using an hyperslab in function of the MPI rank (each rank writes 40x40x40 values)
        WRITE(start, "(I0)") hdfql_mpi_get_rank() * 40
        state = hdfql_execute("INSERT INTO dset[" // start // ":1:1:40] IN PARALLEL VALUES FROM MEMORY 0")
    ELSE
        ! if MPI rank is equal or greater than 3 nothing is written
        state = hdfql_execute("INSERT INTO dset IN PARALLEL NO VALUES")
    END IF

END PROGRAM
```

Please check HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) to get additional information on how to work with HDF5 files in parallel (i.e. with MPI) using this library.

Comment: I would love to use another library, but I'm running this thing on a huge cluster which is  administered from outside. Is there a similar solution in the regular `hdf5`? If you're less familiar with that, that's fine, I can try to translate what you wrote into regular `hdf5`.

Comment: @HaykHakobyan: Unfortunately, not sure how to solve your use-case using other libraries. Hope the example above can give you some hints on how to proceed with the translation though!